# How to delete QFrame in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, pyqt

i try to build a software center GUI similar to ubuntu software center. I'm using pyqt. I created three QFrame object in my GUI. Each QFrame object has a different purpose, one for categories, one for top rated softwares, one for recommended softwares. These three frames are displayed on the main GUI screen. After searching a keyword , i want to show only one frame which contains results on the screen. Hence i need to delete the three frames when i clicked a button. I didn't find any information about deleting frames.

All i found on the web is about deleting widgets from Layout. I already know and implemented this in one of my frames. In this frame , when i clicked a button, i remove some widgets from the frame,etc. My code is like the following:
r 
    self.topRatedAppsFrame=QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
    ...

```
self.horFortopRatedApps = QtGui.QWidget(self.topRatedAppsFrame)
...

self.topRatedAppsList = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.horFortopRatedApps)
...


self.app1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horFortopRatedApps)
self.topRatedAppsList.addWidget(self.app1,0,0)


#########this deletes only widget app1 from topRatedAppsList#########
#########but frame still exists and appears in the screen.i #########
######### want to destroy or delete frame topRatedAppsFrame #########
self.topRatedAppsList.removeWidget(self.app1)
self.app1.deleteLater()
self.app1 = None
####################################################################
```

Hint: What i want to implement is implemented in Ubuntu Software Center. Many frames exists in Ubuntu software center. HOwever when we searched something, everything disappears,only search results are displayed. I want to do the *same* thing. I downloaded the Ubuntu Software Center and examined the source code.Since it is so complex,and gtk is used ,this source code didn't help me. How can i do it? Any guidance or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Creating only one QFrame and filling it with different content each time the search result changes might also be a good option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting or removing the other frames is probably the wrong approach.

It's much more efficient to simply hide/show the frames as needed. There are several ways to achieve this, but a [QStackedLayout](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedlayout.html) sounds like the best fit for your puposes. All you need to do is add each set of frames as a separate layer/page in the stack, then use [setCurrentIndex](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedlayout.html#currentIndex-prop) to bring the required item to the top. A stacked-layout is just like a tab-widget, but without the tab-bar and outer frame.

**EDIT**:

Here's a simple working demo which shows how to use a stacked layout:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        def make_frame(text, parent):
            frame = QtGui.QFrame(parent)
            frame.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
            layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(frame)
            label = QtGui.QLabel(text, frame)
            label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            layout.addWidget(label)
            return frame
        self.splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(self)
        for text in 'ONE TWO THREE'.split():
            self.splitter.addWidget(make_frame(text, self.splitter))
        self.stack = QtGui.QStackedLayout()
        self.stack.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.stack.addWidget(make_frame('FOUR', self))
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Switch', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stack.setCurrentIndex(
                int(self.stack.currentIndex() == 0)))
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addLayout(self.stack)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: QStackedLayout is defined as the following:   QStackedLayout ( QWidget * parent )   , QStackedLayout ( QLayout * parentLayout ) . Namely;i can add widgets and layouts to the QStackedLayout, but i cannot add any QFrame to QStackedLayout according to definiton of QStackedLayout. Only widgets can be hidden/showed ,not frames ,by using QStackedLayout.Thus it doesn't solve my problem. If i'm wrong ,pls correct me @ekhumoro

Comment: @oiyio. You are totally wrong :) It does solve your problem, otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it. Any class which inherits `QWidget` (such as a `QFrame`, `QPushButton`, `QLabel`, etc) can be added, just as with all the other layouts. And in general, for all Qt APIs, wherever you see a parameter of type `QWidget`, `QObject`, etc, any subclass inheriting from that type can be passed as well. (But of course, in PyQt, there is never any need for casting).

Comment: You are totaly true and you convinced me :) I understand the concept better now. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

QFrame is a child of QWidget class. Deleting QWidget is already explained in the question. Thus, QFrame can be deleted in the similar way.

Using QStackLayout is not the solution of this problem. Because, there must be more than one active frame in the window at the same time. However, using QStackLayout only one QFrame(QWidget) can be active at once which is not suitable for this situation.

Comment: I don't why you are making such heavy going of this (and again, you are completely wrong about stacked-layouts). I have added an example to my question which shows how easy it is to achieve what you asked for in your question.